# How to boot Arch Linux installation medium with Secure Boot enabled?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, secure-boot

I've got a new laptop with a Samsung BIOS (version P08AFD) and Aptio Setup Utility. When I try to boot a USB stick with [Arch Linux 2016.10.01](https://www.archlinux.org/download/) it says that the signature is invalid. The [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot) seems to assume that I've already booted into Arch Linux. So I'm stumped for how to continue:

- Are the keys on the ISO somewhere? There is a tool in Aptio to add PK, KEK, DB and DBX files.
- Has the signature been invalidated by me making a custom USB stick from the official installation medium?
- Should this "just work"? I'm at a loss for why a Linux distro would *stop* supporting a common (if controversial) security feature, especially since they seem to have supported it for some time.

The USB stick boots just fine on an older machine without Secure Boot support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flash the ISO on the usb key as you would normally do.

Then:

1. navigate to `~\EFI\boot\`
2. rename `BOOTx64.EFI` as `loader.efi`
3. [download](https://packages.debian.org/sid/shim-signed#pdownload) signed `shim.efi` in the same folder
4. rename it as `BOOTx64.EFI`
5. boot the thing and *enroll from disk* the `~\EFI\boot\loader.efi` hash

EDIT: [relevant bug](https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/53864)

Comment: What does "rename the later as such" mean? Like rename `PreLoader.efi` as `bootx64.efi`?

Comment: Solved! Wow, this is awesome. For anyone else confused, this translates to replacing `bootx64.efi` with `PreLoader.efi`; when I booted, I then followed [these instructions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Secure_Boot#Booting_archiso) and I was all good.

Comment: I guess like I should add the instructions for `shim` now, but I lack the hardware to test it atm.