# Arch Linux ISO issues with EFI (could not authenticate image)

Tags: arch-linux, uefi

I am not able to boot my HP Pavilion 15 which has EFI with the Arch Linux ISO for installation. The error message is: `Selected boot image did not authenticate`

I have tried booting with a DVD as well as a USB flash drive.

The image is: `archlinux-2016.11.01-dual.iso`

How do I get past this?

Comment: Disable the secure boot from the bios settings

Comment: See [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320078/how-to-boot-arch-linux-installation-medium-with-secure-boot-enabled) to boot without disabling secure boot.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by disabling Secure Boot in BIOS settings, as suggested by GAD3R.